# Simple past or past perfect in this example

Tags: grammar, past-tense, past-perfect, simple-past-vs-past-perfect

In the following examples:

- When I was five years old I had a dog.

Is this a past perfect sentence? Here, I know that the 'dog' is not a verb and because we use third form of verb after 'had' so this got me confused.

- I just had a meal.

Is this a simple past sentence? Here, 'meal' is also not a verb.

Comment: Have you read about Past Perfect, Simple Past, etc at all?

Comment: Yes, but not all books explain it very well. I was just confused about the grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these sentences are in the simple past. The past perfect, also known as the pluperfect, is formed when the verb takes on the form *"had [verb]"*, but in your examples, *had* is not acting as an auxiliary verb but rather as a normal verb, since it is not followed by another verb. Since *had* is not an auxiliary verb here, it is the simple past form of *has (to have)*.

Comment: As an example; *I told him that when I was five, I had had a dog*.

Comment: What about the sentence: _"I had to go"_ Here, _go_ is a verb but it's not in the third form. is it correct?

Comment: @user963241- This is also simple past. *Had* is the main verb, which is followed by the infinitive *to go*.